# How to select a file with selecting from Gallery or File Manager in android

Tags: android, file, select

I am using the following code for selecting file, it opens file
manager to select a file.

What I want is to show a dialog to choose the application first for
selecting a file, as shown in the image:

[image: dialog to choose application]

```
public class ActivityTestActivity extends Activity {
      final int ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE = 1;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent chooseFile;
            Intent intent;
            chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            chooseFile.setType("file/*");
            intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
          }
        });
      }

      @Override
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {
          case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
              Uri uri = data.getData();
              String filePath = uri.getPath();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The chooser options depends on the file type, so for example if you want to retrieve images you have to use `image/*` in `setType` method.

Edit: use `*/*` for all types

Comment: In my case, file can be an image, pdf, word file etc